# Import Excel using .mdf database

Tags: sql-server, excel

How to import Excel file into a SQL Server (`.mdf`) database to a certain table with Visual Studio 2010?

I have searched it for hours and google it but haven't got any good response yet.

Comment: You cannot "import" into a .mdf file - you need to mount it to access the database contained inside. SQL Server Management Studio will help you achive this and also offer a Data Import Wizard for your Excel data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sql Server Import Export Wizard that will help you to insert data in table from excel file. This can be found in start menu in windows. You can attach .mdf file in SQL management studio then use Import Export Wizard to fill you data in table from excel sheet

Comment: Excel data cannot be imported directly into a .mdf file. SQL Server Management Studio will help you achieve this but the question asks using visual studio, interesting question.